# Is there any option to identify the angularjs page loading using selenium ngwebdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

Im using selenium ngWebdriver for angular js application. For page loading i have used below code,

```
ngdriver=new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
```

But timeout exception is thrown.so Im using `thread.sleep`.

Is there any option to identify page loading or we have to check with development side.